# Describing the past events with proper tense choice

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I want to describe a past incident. Like, a few months ago I faced a bike accident. I tell the story to one of my friends. I describe the story in the past tense. Like,

> I wanted to buy groceries. So I went to the supermarket. I was on my bike. Suddenly, another biker turned into my bike lane from a side street. He sped up and tried to overtake me. He lost control of his bike and skidded.

Now my question is when I describe a past situation, should I describe it totally in the past tense or I should combine past and present tense?

Like,

> He speeds up and tries to overtake me. He loses control of his bike and skid.

How would a native English speaker express this last example?

Comment: It's a question of style.

Comment: It is, as Hot Licks said, a matter of style. Mixing in present tense sounds less formal. If you say "He speeds up..." then the next sentence should be "He loses control of his bike and skid**s**."

Comment: Using the present tense for past events is called [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). It's perfectly grammatical, and is used to create a sense of immediacy. But choose either that or more explicit past tenses; don't mix the two.

Comment: I do not describe historical events. It is my personal experience. Therefore, which one is right?

Comment: @Encipher - It's in your history.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I should mix up the tenses?

Comment: _Historical_ in this sense doesn't mean 'describing historical events', but 'telling a story'. You can make the (true) story of your accident seem more vivid by telling it in the present tense - but, as Andrew says, don't mix the tenses.

Comment: Okay Thank you all